# Snowflake time zone conversion

Tags: sql, datetime, timezone, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, timezone-offset

In a fact table the grain of the data is `CustomerId` and `DateHour`. The `DateHour` data is in UTC timezone, but for the sake of the reporting the `DateHour` is converted into the local timezone which `America/Halifax`. Due to day light saving the `DateHour` column is having duplicates.

```
alter session set timezone = 'UTC';
select '2022-03-13T05:00:00Z'::timestamp as UTC_Time, CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC','America/Halifax','2022-03-13T05:00:00Z') as converted_time
union all 
select '2022-03-13T06:00:00Z'::timestamp as UTC_Time, CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC','America/Halifax','2022-03-13T06:00:00Z') as converted_time
union all 
select '2022-11-06T04:00:00Z'::timestamp as UTC_Time, CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC','America/Halifax','2022-11-06T04:00:00Z') as converted_time
union all 
select '2022-11-06T05:00:00Z'::timestamp as UTC_Time, CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC','America/Halifax','2022-11-06T05:00:00Z') as converted_time;
```

Output of the above query:

[image]

On March 13th an hour has been lost in the time zone and on November 6th the same hour appeared twice. Because of this the grain of the data is no longer unique. i.e. the combination of the `CustomerId` and `DateHour` is not an unique combination.

How to handle time zone conversion so that there are no duplicates in the `DateHour` column after time zone conversion?

Comment: Fundamentally you can't - because that's how time zone transitions work. Sometimes periods of local time are skipped, and sometimes they're repeated. Ignoring how you'd implement it, what would you *expect* the data to look like?

Comment: Snowflake does not internally store the timezone. It stores the timezone offset from UTC. So "HALIFAX_TIME" is going to change from UTC -4 to UTC -3 on daylight saving time and to UTC -3 to UTC -4 changing back to standard time. If you're storing the timestamps as timestamp_ltz then you should be see it displayed with an offset like -0300 and you can use that to disambiguate the two 1am times when switching back to standard time from DST.